# How do I put an absolute positioned img into a <td>?

Tags: html, image, html-table

I am trying to put an absolutely positioned image inside a td.  The following code creates unwanted gaps above the image in FF 3.6 and makes the image disappear in IE 7.  I have included the relevant external style sheet elements before the table code.

```
#leftColTopTdImg
{
 padding:0px;
 margin:0px;
 position:relative;
}
#navLinksTD
{
position:relative;
padding:0px;
margin:0px;
}
#navLinksBoxDiv
{
position:relative;
width:100%;
height:100%;

padding:0px;
margin:0px;
}
#navLinksInBox
{
position:relative;
}
#navLinksBg
{
position:absolute;
width:100%;
height:100%;
}

    <table width="222px" cellspacing="0px" cellpadding="0px" border="0px">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td id="leftColTopTdImg"><img width="222px" height="77px" alt="" src="../leftcol_top.jpg" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="navLinksTD">
                <div id="navLinksBoxDiv">
                    <img id="navLinksBg" src="../menu_combined_2r.jpg" alt="The background for the navigation link box.  It has a vertical gradient going from light to dark and then dark to light blude" />
                    <ul id="navLinksInBox">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Driving While Intoxicated</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Sex Crimes</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">2nd Driving While Intoxicated</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">2nd Sex Crimes</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                <!--End of navLinksBoxDiv-->                                                            
                </div>
                <img id="menuBottom" src="../menu_bottomedge.jpg" alt="The bottom of the menu" />
            <!--End of navLinksTD-->
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I have read alot about positioning an absolute div within a td but the same trick does not seem to work in this case.  How do I put an absolute positioned img in a td?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to see what is wrong without seeing the result, but a few things I've noticed straight away:

You haven't set the positions for your absolute-positioned image (i.e. top:0; left:0;)... this could well be the cause of your disappearing image

You also haven't specified the padding & margins to be 0 for the images themselves.

If it is the table itself that is causing the problem, you could also try:
    table { border-collapse:collapse;}
to ensure the borders are collapsed and not leaving gaps.